# Change sensitive info to ******* in Django admin change view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a following question.

For example I have a admin class in Django:

```
@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (‘field1’, ‘field2’, ‘field3’)
    fields = (‘field1’, ‘field2’, ‘field3’,  ‘key’)   
    …
```

As you can see change view of admin has ‘`key`’ fields which contains sensitive information that I don’t want to show to anyone in change view .

Question is – is it possible to change ‘`key`’ displayed data to `‘*******’` in admin change view page in case `‘key’` has some data and to `‘-’` if it does not?

How to do it in List view - i know

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you add `key` field in `fields`  if you dont want anyone to see its values ?

Comment: i just want to show that key is generated already.

Answer (score 0):

```
@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (‘field1’, ‘field2’, ‘field3’)
    fields = (‘field1’, ‘field2’, ‘field3’,  ‘key’)   
    …

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj.sensitive_field:
            self.exclude = ("sensitive_field", )
        form = super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form
```

You can override the admin form and the manipulate it as you want.

Comment: This will hide fields but the question is masking sensitive data with “****”